# Opening multiple hyperlinks in one point directly from QGIS

Tags: qgis, hyperlink

I have an enormous shapefile and each point has about twenty different attributes. About five of these twenty are hyperlinks.

Is there anyway to open these directly from selecting a point in QGIS?

For example, in ArcGIS Explorer, you can click on a point, look at the point's attributes, click on the hyperlink, and it will open adobe/autocad/etc.

I installed hot links plugin but couldn't figure out how to use it, let alone any information about it online.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Actions in QGIS. Right click layer > Properties > goto the Action tab

The Add default action button, can give some hints.

[image: Actions]

The [% "WWW" %] is a column called WWW with hyperlinks as values.

Then you can use the Run Feature Action button next to the Identify Feature button to start the action.

You can also embed the url in a form by selecting a webview as edit widget under the Fields tab of a layer properties.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info! I still don't totally understand how it works though- I have five fields that hold different paths to different pdfs & dwgs on a server....where do I put the field name? Do I have to make a different action for each field?

Comment: Yes, you have to make an action for each field. This very simple action is just the field name. You could also move the filepath out of the field value and put it in the action like  C:\mypath\[%"www"%], if all the pdf are in the same folder. Try the 'Add default actions' button to see som samples of different actions.